# How do I set Dutch date language?

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

Full string date formats are shown in English, how do I format these into Dutch?
We're using EE5 and Calendar 3.x for EE 4.x - 5.x.
Are there any language packages or something I can use?

Thanx.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need the day/month names to be in Dutch? This depends on the installed locales on your server. If the dutch locale is installed you can use https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/hippo-datetime